# How can i update document in mongo db using .net(c#) driver without using Builders?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am using `MongoDb` `.net` driver in which i have to update document based on certain condition.

Here is how my `find` query looks like in `c#` `mongo` driver

```
DbService.conversations.Find (new BsonDocument ("_id", new ObjectId ("obje-id-here"))).FirstOrDefault ();
```

How can i update specific field of document based on certain `_id` using `Mongodb .net` driver without using `Builders`?

**Note : **

I have tried this update query

```
var updateResultFromQuery = await DbService.conversations.UpdateOneAsync(Builders<RawBsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("_id", "5e01a89e5f317324780b7f83"),Builders<RawBsonDocument>.Update.Set("visitorName", "Guest41815"));
Console.WriteLine("after update response --- "+updateResultFromQuery.ToJson());
```

But it's not updating the value even i am receiving update response like this

```
{ "_t" : "Acknowledged" }
```

Comment: i've written a library that can update specific parts of documents without using builders. here's the [wiki entry](https://github.com/dj-nitehawk/MongoDB.Entities/wiki/02.-Entities#updating-entities-without-retrieving) for the update method.

Comment: Can you tell me in your answer that how can i update document based on multiple conditions using your library? just give me small example.

Comment: @RyanGunner I have to update document based on these conditions 

where _id == obj._id and object.agent.email == obj.email. So now tell me short example according to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved updating my document without using any third party library using these options

```
var filter = new BsonDocument(new Dictionary<string, dynamic> () {
  {
    "_id",  new BsonObjectId("object-id-here")
  },
  {
    "assigned_to.email" , agentEmail
  }
});

var updateDoc = new BsonDocument(new Dictionary<string, dynamic> () {
  {
    "$set", new BsonDocument("assigned_to.$.avgResponseTime", Convert.ToDouble(obj.agentChatAvgResponseTime))
  }
 });
var updateQueryResult = DbService.conversations.UpdateOne(filter, updateDoc, new UpdateOptions {IsUpsert = false });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply [ReplaceOne](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollectionExtensions_ReplaceOne__1.htm)  object instead of updating it , that way you wont be forced to use builders but you will be doing a find and replace instead. 2 database operations instead of one. You can then update your object in memory instead.

`Collection.ReplaceOne(filter, replacement, new UpdateOptions() { IsUpsert = false });`

Comment: Will it require any `namespace` import?

Comment: And this query is not updating just searching. I think you are missing something in your answer. I want to update document don't want to  find document

Comment: con you specify the syntax for `filter` and `replacement`?

Comment: @FahadHassan replacement is your entity object. Filter is your lookup.

Comment: I know this but i don't know the filter object syntax. Please specify that in your answer

Comment: @FahadHassan I suggest applying yourself - this is not a code writing service and hand holding platform.

Answer (score 0):

here's an example of create/update/find as requested:

```cs
using MongoDB.Entities; //Install-Package MongoDB.Entities
using MongoDB.Entities.Core;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class Customer : Entity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Agent Agent { get; set; }
    }

    public class Agent
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            new DB("test", "localhost");

            // create a customer with embedded agent
            var customer = new Customer
            {
                Name = "Customer A",
                Agent = new Agent { Name = "Agent Uno", Email = "uno@youknow.com" }
            };
            customer.Save();

            // update customer name
            DB.Update<Customer>()
              .Match(c =>
                     c.ID == customer.ID &&
                     c.Agent.Email == "uno@youknow.com")
              .Modify(c =>
                      c.Name, "Updated Customer")
              .Execute();

            // find updated customer
            var cst = DB.Find<Customer>()
                        .Match(customer.ID)
                        .Execute()
                        .Single();

            Console.WriteLine($"Customer Name: {cst.Name}");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it necessary to have my object(That has to be updated) of type `Entity` ?

Comment: It throws following error when i am trying to import your given imports on your given `Wiki` docs. 

`The type or namespace name `Entities` doesn't exist in the namespace 'MongoDB.'`

Comment: Also your library is not compatible with `asp.net core 2.2.0`. It is throwing this error on running the project

`Version conflict detected for Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection. Install/reference Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection 3.1.0 directly to project analytics to resolve this issue.
D:\OfficeProjects\beelinksanalytics\analytics.csproj : error NU1107:  analytics -> MongoDB.Entities 8.16.0 -> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection (>= 3.1.0)`

Comment: Yes but it is throwing compatibility error mentioned above in my comments

Comment: Can you give me example of MongoDb driver update query using Builder?

Comment: Can you give me example of Mongo update query using Builder? Because i added your mentioned line in my csproj and still i am getting that error. So please update your answer and give me upadate query example using Builder
My document in database is like this
`{username : "fahad", age : 23, assigned_to : [{email : "fahad@gmail.com", avgTime : 0},{email : "alex@gmail.com", avgTime : 0}]}`
I have multiple objects in document's `assigned_to` array field i have to find the specific document in `assigned_to` array where email = "alex@gmail.com" and want to update that object's `avgTime` field

Comment: @FahadHassan i see you've solved your issue. fyi, i've fixed compatibility with asp.net core v2.1 and above with the library. have a good day!